# Sending data from external api into wordpress database

Tags: wordpress

I would like to make a wordpress plugin that will display summarized information from a table stored in the wordpress database.  My question is how do I process the HTTP POST from the remote service using wordpress methods?

I was looking for a tutorial that would illuminate this process.

I cold just use straight php/mysql and store the info directly to the table, but I would like to do it "correctly" using Wordpress to sanitize the data and keep project under the wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use wp_remote_post:

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(),
    'body' => array( 'username' => 'bob', 'password' => '1234xyz' ),
    'cookies' => array()
    )
);

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'Response:<pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

And after you receive the data and perform any required modifications, you can insert them into custom table using $wpdb:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert( 
    'table', 
    array( 
        'column1' => 'value1', 
        'column2' => 123 
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%d' 
    ) 
);
```

this will require creating a custom table, which can be created like that:

```
global $wpdb;    
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
     $custom_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_table_name';
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $custom_table (
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
    col1 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    col2 varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    ) $charset_collate;";

        dbDelta($sql);
```

refer to wp_remote_post, $wpdb and wp_insert_post in WordPress documentation for more information

Comment: I don't think that wp_remote_post will help.  The remote server/web service sends the data real-time to a URL of my choice. I need to create a service to receive that information. But thank you anyway.